# counting recursively files and directories

Tags: directory, recursive

I need some help for this :

Let's say I am in a directory and in this directory there are other directories and files etc...

I would like to use a recursive function to count all the files and directories in it and in the sub too.

I know that I can solve the issue by using wc ... grep or find but I'm really trying to use my first recursive function here.

This is what I have done so far but it doesn't work properly

```
    counting(){


    for i in $(ls -a $1)
    do
          if [ -d $1/$i ];then
          let d++
          cd $1/$i       
          counting $i
          cd ..
          elif [ -f $1/$i ];then
          let f++
          fi
    done

  }

counting $1
echo "number of files = $f ; number of directories = $d"
```

Comment: @Theophrastus If you run it in a subshell, the changes to `$d` and `$f` won't propagate upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can improve (without any claim to completeness):

1. ***Never* parse the output of `ls`.**
   Your script will break as soon as any file or directory name contains whitespace (which is perfectly legitimate on most modern filesystems).
   Instead use the globbing feature of your shell:

   ```
   shopt -s dotglob # to make the * glob match hidden files (like ls -a)
   for i in "$1"/*
   ```
2. **Always quote variables.**
   Your shell looks at whitespace characters (space, newline, …) to determine where one command argument ends and another starts. Consider the following example:

   ```
   filename="foo bar"

   touch $filename
   # gets expanded to `touch foo bar`, so it creates two files named "foo" and "bar"

   touch "$filename"
   # gets expanded to `touch "foo bar`", so it creates a single file named "foo bar"
   ```
3. A `cd` too many

   ```
   cd $1/$i       
   counting $i

   # which in turn calls ...
   ls -a $1
   ```

   `ls`-parsing and unquoted variables aside, this will try to list the contents of the directory `./foo/bar/bar` when all you've got is `./foo/bar`.